# need explaination with cruise control .net step by step

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I have installed cruise control .net 1.8.3.0.but important thing is that I do not know how to work with ccnet.I have gone through with so many link in google but i did not catch that.i am a beginner for it. i know msbuild.using it ,I have create publish folder for my application.

Could you please expalin me step by step.if better given by sample demo.

Answer (score 0):

Well, check out our documentation in our Wiki.

There you'll find a good starting point in the [Scenarios](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Scenarios) Section.

It explains step by step on how to start.